# Is it possible to serialize an object into data which will be passed to the compiler pass?

Tags: symfony

I have a symfony bundle which needs to store a lot of data. Currently said data is stored as arrays, read and put into the memory of a service. While this approach works, it's not very readable.

It's not possible to simply set an argument to a list of X, as such I'm unable to store said data in a better way.

My data will not change between cache compiles, so I was wondering if there's anything where I can do something like the following

```php
class MyModel {
  public function __construct(
    public readonly string $from,
    public readonly string $to
  ) {}
}


// on compiler pass
$model = new MyModel('aaa', 'bbbb');

$myDefinition->addMethodCall('myMethod', [[$model], $otherScalarArguments]);
```

I was also wondering if Symfony's expressions could help in this case, but I'm unsure.
My current use of `->addMethodCall` has 7 arguments, so this would make my life easier.

Comment: Can you update your question to elaborate a bit more about why you cannot set an argument to a list of X? Normally it's possible.

Comment: You could serialize the object in the compile pass and pass in the resulting string.  The service itself would then have to deserialize it which it probably not ideal.  But like the previous comment I'm not sure how you got from having a bunch of unreadable array data to your posted code.

Comment: @Cerad yes, I'm aware of that possibility. However Symfony's expressions are able to do this without serializing if you want to pass a result of a call (`@=service('xxx').someMethod()`)

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought the container could handle this sort of thing so I reproduced the issue and got:

```
Unable to dump a service container if a parameter is an object or a resource.
```

So even though you can pass an object as an argument, the caching code which writes the compiled container out as a php file is not smart enough to handle it.  Note: it is often useful to add error messages to questions.

The trick is to serialize the object in the pass itself and then unserialize it in the service.

```
class MyService
{
  private MyModel $myModel;

  public function __construct(string $myModel)
  {
    $this->myModel = unserialize($myModel);

    dump($this->myModel);
  }
}
# pass
       $model = serialize(new MyModel('aaa', 'bbbb'));

       $def = $container->getDefinition(MyService::class);
       $def->addArgument($model);
```

I tested it and it all seemed to work.  I did take take the liberty of simplifying the original code a bit but it will work work just fine for addMethodCall as well.

Might be worthwhile proposing this to the Symfony core group.  It is niche functionality but might come in handy now and then.

Comment: I am aware of this approach but it misses the point as you will waste runtime on deserialization.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm also curious if someone can come up with different approach.  I'm a little bit skeptical about your runtime performance concerns.  Those model objects have to be created somehow when the service is instantiated.  I don't think there is much difference between the new operator and deserialization.  At least not enough to notice.  And the runtime overhead associated with expressions is?  In any event, good luck.

Comment: the thing is that symfony has no overhead with that usecase as it gets compiled into the container methods.